# High latency when using FUSE to pass through to tmpfs + swap

Tags: filesystems, swap, fuse, tmpfs

I'm creating a shim layer over an in-memory file system (tmpfs) so that I can intercept the file system commands and do extra processing (the end goal is to replicate the writes over the network for fault tolerance). To intercept the file system commands, I'm using FUSE. For the in-memory file system, I'm using tmpfs. To overcome the small memory size, I've created enough swap space over SSD for tmpfs to use.

To summarize, I have a directory `dir` which is mounted with tmpfs. I created another directory `shim`, which all applications write to. FUSE is mounted on `shim` and redirects all operations to `dir`.

With some microbenchmarking with Filebench directly writing to `dir`, I've found that tmpfs + swap has super low latency, especially when compared to ext4 on disk. There's no perceptible slowdown when tmpfs switches from writing to RAM to writing to swap space, I'm assuming because of some clever readaheads.

When I overlay it with FUSE with [passthrough_hp.c](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/passthrough_hp.cc), however, even with multi-threading on, file creation becomes super slow, some 60x higher latency than tmpfs + swap. Using `htop`, I noticed that it only slows down when it writes to swap instead of memory (memory fills up very quickly, then swap slowly increases). Otherwise, FUSE itself has quite little overhead.

Does anyone know why FUSE gets the latency hit when using swap and tmpfs on its own doesn't, and how I would optimize away this additional overhead?

Comment: I've done more benchmarking, and it seems like this problem is only apparently on passthrough_hp.c, and not on the other passthrough programs (passthrough_fh, passthrough_ll, etc)